# CSS3 rotate parent div but keep content horizontal

Tags: css, rotation

I have the following HTML as,

```
<a href="#" class="outer"><span class="inner">Text</span></a>
```

I am trying to apply a background color and rotate it at 45 degrees to look like a diamond using the transform property. But I want the text to stay horizontal But I don't know how to achieve this. I have tried:

```
.outer{
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color:#fdc300;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.inner{
    color:#FFF;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform:  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

and other failed attempts and getting nowhere. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `display: inline-block` to `span.inner`:

```
.inner{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ew90tyoq/)

**EDIT:**

To center text you also need:

```
.inner{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ew90tyoq/2/)

Comment: Thank you for providing this. While this does fix the horizontal issue, I can't get text to stay inside the outer div.